# Laravel syntax error, unexpected ')' on ubuntu nginx web server but works on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04, web-development-server

i'm getting this syntax error when my code runs on the server but locally there is no error.
here the method below and
[here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdpyY.png)

```
 public function completeProfile(Request $request, LabScientist $labScientist)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'date_of_birth' => ['required', 'date'],
            'gender' => ['required', 'min:1', 'max:2'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10', 'max:14'],
            'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
        $token_string = \request()->session()->token();
        // auth()->user()->update($data);
        auth()->user()->update(
            array_merge(
                $data,
                ['password' => Hash::make($data['password'])],
            ) //fails on this line
        );
        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Comment: Remove the comma at the end of the line before the failure. Different php versions maybe?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Thanks man, that did it. Different php versions too

Comment: Just to give clear info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.new-features.php#migration73.new-features.core.trailing-commas
"Trailing commas in function and method calls are now allowed. " since PHP 7.3